# How to fix the Failed to resolve the Android SDK path. ANDROID_HOME is set to a non-existing path: C:Users\mukes\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk error?

Tags: android, expo

I am trying to use expo to create a react native app. This is my first time using expo. When I tried to run expo using android, it gives me back the following error:

```
    Failed to resolve the Android SDK path. ANDROID_HOME is set to a non-existing path: 
    C:Users\mukes\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    Failed to resolve the Android SDK path. ANDROID_HOME is set to a non-existing path: 
    C:Users\mukes\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    Failed to resolve the Android SDK path. ANDROID_HOME is set to a non-existing path: 
    C:Users\mukes\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    Failed to resolve the Android SDK path. ANDROID_HOME is set to a non-existing path: 
    C:Users\mukes\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    Failed to resolve the Android SDK path. ANDROID_HOME is set to a non-existing path: 
    C:Users\mukes\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    Failed to resolve the Android SDK path. ANDROID_HOME is set to a non-existing path: 
    C:Users\mukes\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    Failed to resolve the Android SDK path. ANDROID_HOME is set to a non-existing path: 
    C:Users\mukes\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    Failed to resolve the Android SDK path. ANDROID_HOME is set to a non-existing path: 
    C:Users\mukes\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    › Opening exp://192.168.0.142:19000 on SM_A536E
    Failed to resolve the Android SDK path. ANDROID_HOME is set to a non-existing path: 
    C:Users\mukes\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    Failed to resolve the Android SDK path. ANDROID_HOME is set to a non-existing path: 
    C:Users\mukes\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    Failed to resolve the Android SDK path. ANDROID_HOME is set to a non-existing path: 
    C:Users\mukes\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    Failed to resolve the Android SDK path. ANDROID_HOME is set to a non-existing path: 
    C:Users\mukes\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    Failed to resolve the Android SDK path. ANDROID_HOME is set to a non-existing path: 
    C:Users\mukes\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    Failed to resolve the Android SDK path. ANDROID_HOME is set to a non-existing path: 
    C:Users\mukes\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    Failed to resolve the Android SDK path. ANDROID_HOME is set to a non-existing path: 
    C:Users\mukes\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    Failed to resolve the Android SDK path. ANDROID_HOME is set to a non-existing path: 
    C:Users\mukes\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

I have set the environment variable on path as ANDROID_HOME pointing to C:Users\mukes\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk.

I tried to use Android because the normal way of running it using the app doesn't seem to work on my laptop either. When I try to use tunnel, I am met with this error instead:

```
    Error starting ngrok: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? I have already spent like 2 days with this problem. Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The path seems to be missing a backslash there, after C: 
`C:\Users\mukes\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`  .                                                                       
 Also verify from file browser, the path specified exists.

Comment: I added the backslash, and now that error disappeared, but now my web emulator is blank, and when I run it on mobile, it comes up with "Uncaught error : java.net.SocketTimoutException"